# Why does the app function in Azure refuse to update?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a function in Java and I am now trying to create an endpoint in Azure using the function app. In a tutorial I followed I generated a new functions project so I got the HTTP Trigger code that Azure uses and placed my Java code from the function. When I get the code URL from the portal and runs it through curl in powershell I constantly get this message: "please pass a name on the query string or in the request body" even though my code is changed and doesn't contain this message.

How do I fix this? I have tried to remove the function from the Azure portal and updating it, I have tried to synchronize it and run it again but it refuses to update and actually use the code I use.

Comment: Append the query string `?name=<YOUR_NAME>` to this URL and execute the request.

Comment: Or  paste your latest code.

Answer (score 0):

Inline with George what is saying.

The URL that calls your HTTP triggered function should be in the following format:

[image]

So Append the query string ?name= to this URL and execute the request

Answer (score 0):

By default HTTP trigger for the created function is in this format.

> http://.azurewebsites.net/api/

You can also customize this route using this route property like this **"products/{category:alpha}/{id:int}"**

Now you can hit the route like this

> http://.azurewebsites.net/api/products/electronics/357

The example below is showing how to do this.

```
@FunctionName("routeTest")
  public HttpResponseMessage<String> routeTest(
      @HttpTrigger(name = "req",
                    methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
                    route = "products/{category:alpha}/{id:int}") 
                    HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
      @BindingName("category") String category,
      @BindingName("id") int id,
       final ExecutionContext context
  ) {
           ....
           context.getLogger().info("We have " + category + " with id " + id);
           ....
  }
```

Now the issue you're facing is due to the missing params/query value. The value is empty.
You need to pass the value after the end f your http triger function. As below.

```
http://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<funcname>?name="Value for the param"
```